# Convert PNG to TIFF with Transparency and CMYK

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I am trying hard to convert `PNG`s to `TIFF`s using a Batch File. However, the resulting files lack transparency.

```
S:\*.*\mogrify -path H:\*.*\blau -format tiff  H:\*.*\Raw\*.png
pause
S:\*.*\mogrify -fuzz 20%% -fill blue -opaque black H:\*.*\blau\*.tiff
S:\*.*\mogrify -colorspace cmyk H:\*.*\blau\*.tiff
S:\*.*\mogrify -fuzz 60%% -transparent white H:\*.*\blau\*.tiff
```

The `TIFF`s have a white background afterwards which I have verified using `PhotoShop`. What is wrong here? How can I get the resulting files to not lose transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Although TIFF format, technically, does support transparency, it is a dark matter in general. Even some Adobe applications do not support this correctly, if ever. Perhaps, neither does your application; or it may have support in theory, but messes something upon format-to-format conversion.